# Received Webform email does not show the @ symbol

Tags: webforms, emails

When we receive webform submissions emails, the email element is not allowing the @ symbol to pull through.  The email are displayed with the word at instead of @.  Example - steve [at] google.com.  How can we fix this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this at all. Assuming I understand the question, which I think is that an email address entered in the form is shown in an email sent by an email handler. If I am assuming right, perhaps some other mailer module is doing that at your end. Anyway, this question needs more information to be answerable with facts.

Comment: Hey @k-con , make sure that the email field in your webform is configured correctly. go to the Email element settings, and ensure that the "Email format" is set to "Email" rather than "Default" or "Plain text." This should allow the "@" symbol to be properly displayed. Also `[webform_submission:values:email_field]`. If you are manually adding the email field to the email template, ensure that you are using the correct token.